# CakePhp related combobox not charging

Tags: php, cakephp, combobox, models

I've been working with a project in CakePhp using 3 tables (Benefiaciries, Programs and Beneficiaries_Programs) the 3rd table is only to make the right relations, one beneficiary can have one or more programs. My problem is that i need to save the beneficiary along with their programs in a single step, but when I try to load a combo with the programs this is being shown empty, I already tried all I could but still can't fix it.

Models (relations)

```
//Beneficiary
    public $hasMany = array(
    'Personsprogram' => array(
        'className' => 'Personsprogram',
        'foreignKey' => 'beneficiary_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),'Program'
);

//Program
public $hasMany = array(
    'Personsprogram' => array(
        'className' => 'Personsprogram',
        'foreignKey' => 'program_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);

//Personsprogram
    public $belongs = array(
    'Beneficiary' => array(
        'className' => 'Beneficiary',
        'foreignKey' => 'beneficiary_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Program' => array(
        'className' => 'Program',
        'foreignKey' => 'program_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Beneficiary view (add)

```
<?php
//This is the combo what was supposed to be charging the programs so I could pick one.
    echo $this->Form->input('Personsprogram.program_id', array('label'=>'Programs'));
    echo $this->Form->input('date');
    echo $this->Form->input('locality_id');
    echo $this->Form->input('f_surname');
    echo $this->Form->input('s_surname');
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('curp');
    echo $this->Form->input('sex');
?>
```

Controller

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Beneficiaries Controller
 *
 * @property Beneficiary $Beneficiary
 * @property PaginatorComponent $Paginator
 */
App::uses('Personsprogram', 'Model');
App::uses('Program', 'Model');
class BeneficiariesController extends AppController {
//public $uses = array('Locality','Program','Municipality','Personsprogram');

/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Beneficiary->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('beneficiaries', $this->Paginator->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Beneficiary->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid beneficiary'));
        }
        $options = array('conditions' => array('Beneficiary.' .     $this->Beneficiary->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->set('beneficiary', $this->Beneficiary->find('first', $options));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Beneficiary->create();
            if ($this->Beneficiary->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The beneficiary has been     saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The beneficiary could not be     saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $localities = $this->Beneficiary->Locality->find('list');
        $nutritionists = $this->Beneficiary->Nutritionist->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('localities', 'nutritionists'));
    }

/**
 * edit method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Beneficiary->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid beneficiary'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Beneficiary->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The beneficiary has been     saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The beneficiary could not be     saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Beneficiary.' .     $this->Beneficiary->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Beneficiary->find('first', $options);
        }
        $localities = $this->Beneficiary->Locality->find('list');
        $nutritionists = $this->Beneficiary->Nutritionist->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('localities', 'nutritionists'));
    }

/**
 * delete method
 *
 * @throws NotFoundException
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->Beneficiary->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Beneficiary->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid beneficiary'));
        }
        $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Beneficiary->delete()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The beneficiary has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The beneficiary could not be deleted.     Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }}
   ?>
```

So the combo is not showing anything but an empty field.

I would appreciate any advice or help you could give me about what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your controller too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out how to fix this after a long research...

All I had to do was to add this to the "ADD" controller

```
    $dependencies = $this->Beneficiary->Personsprogram->Program->Dependency->find('list');
    $programs = $this->Beneficiary->Personsprogram->Program->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Program.id', 'Program.name'),
    'conditions' => array('Program.name LIKE' => '%%'),
    'recursive' => 0));
    $this->set(compact('dependencies','programs'));
```

So now I get a list of my dependencies and programs and in my view I just need to call the field using

```
$this->Form->input("my_field");
```